# Its posible to make inner join between two domain class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, inner-join

If i have two domain class

**Class A**

```
Class A {
 int product_id
 int price
 String store
}
```

and **Class B**

```
Class B{
int product_id
String product_desc
}
```

Now in my controller i want to know if there is a way executequery to make a inner join by **product_id** to get the description of the product

I dont know if this its the correct way, if im wrong please guide me to make the best perfomance posible

Comment: What is `A` and `B`? How about their real names? It is possible to execute a raw sql but the design looks odd so tell us what is the actual problem rather than telling what you came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is... it depends.

If you hit the database directly by running SQL, then yes, you can create the inner join.

```
A.withNewSession { session ->
    session.createSQLQuery('SELECT B.product_desc FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.product_id = B.product_id' WHERE A.product_id = 1).list()
}
```

If this is what you want, you can read more about it in my article [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/running-sql-queries-from-grails/).

But since you're using Grails, most likely what you want is to use GORM, which is Grail's object-relational-mapper. However, GORM/Hibernate does not allow you to create joins on-the-fly like you can with SQL. You can't even do it with HQL. Instead, you'll need to define the association between your domain classes in advance:

```
Class A {
    int product_id
    int price
    String store
    B b
}

Class B{
   int product_id
   String product_desc
}
```

In the example above, `A` has a many-to-one association to `B`. So once you have an instance of `A`, you can get to its `B`:

```
def a = A.findByProductId(1)
def desc = a.b.product_desc
```

In this case I used a dynamic finder, but there's also where queries, criteria queries, and HQL. I have a series of articles for these [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/).

*Note: The above code is an approximation because the domain classes you posted are so well sanitized that I can't tell what's really going on. But it should give you a sense of the possibilities.*